# facebook login error: An error occurred. Please try later

Tags: php, facebook

I am working on my website and I just added Facebook login. I asked my friend to test it, but when he tries it, it gives him the error message that says "An error occured. Please try again later." when I tried to login myself with my own Facebook account, I was able to register successfully. will someone tell me what to do. 
i have enabled App in Sandbox and i have given localhost url as Site URL.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in your facebook application page to enable/disable sandbox mode.

If sand box mode is on only the owner of app can access it, It needs to be diasbled to others to use.

Go to apps page and edit it : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

See the below image:

[image]